# dividend/divisor vs. numerator/denominator

Tags: terminology, mathematics, programming

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29):

> In the expression a ÷ b = c, a is called the dividend or numerator, b the divisor or denominator and the result c is called the quotient.

What's most common (in the context of programming)?

1. dividend/divisor
2. numerator/denominator

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Dividend* and *divisor* are terms commonly associated with [long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) while *numerator* and *denominator* are the preferred terms when [working with fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29).

*Operators, operands, parameters,* and *arguments* are usually the terms employed in programming. If any of the OP's listed terms are at all utilised, it will very likely be *numerator* and *denominator* (in their mathematical sense).